# Plot centers of class ellipses on a PCA biplot

Tags: r, pca

I was wondering if it was possible to write a function, or if there is an existing function or script that would allow me to plot the centers of the circles and ellipses generated in a PCA.

The following is my code

```
#PCA FUNCTION
fancy.pca <- prcomp(DATA2C ,scale = TRUE)

#FANCY PRINTING OF PCA: GROUPING COLOR / SCHEME / TITLE
g<-ggbiplot(fancy.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
            groups = factor(DATA2C.class), ellipse = T, circle = T)
g<- g+ scale_color_discrete(name = '') 
g<- g+ theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')+
  ggtitle("Jamaica Bay W-E Distribution PCA ")


print(g)
```

And I am attaching an image of my plot [image]

Comment: (1) Could you explain what you mean by "circles and ellipses generated in a PCA"? (2) If you are looking for descriptions of solutions, this is a good site to ask, but if you just want the software or code, we're not the place for that.

Comment: #PCA FUNCTION
fancy.pca <- prcomp(DATA2C ,scale = TRUE)

#FANCY PRINTING OF PCA: GROUPING COLOR / SCHEME / TITLE
g<-ggbiplot(fancy.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
            groups = factor(DATA2C.class), ellipse = T, circle = T)
g<- g+ scale_color_discrete(name = '') 
g<- g+ theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')+
  ggtitle("Jamaica Bay W-E Distribution PCA ")


print(g)        does this help ?

Comment: I'm interested in possible solution. I'd like to plot the origin of the circles and ellipses that i have generated  instead of the actual circles/ellipses if that makes sense...

Comment: @whuber I think after the edits this is pretty clear but a programming question that should probably be migrated to SO (?).

Comment: what is SO? if that's the case I'm happy to take this down and post there.

Comment: SO is StackOverflow.